# Surface - Card Game WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I've been asked to make a simple card game in WPF designed to work with Microsoft Pixel Sense Tables (Version 1).

I've had experience in creating user applications in WPF and even for the Surface but I am quite new to building games. I've had a look at XNA and I am going through the documentation as we speak.

The card game has three different stages and I am looking at completing Stage 1 for now. Stage 1 involves creation of two sets of cards. One set of cards has a word and the other set of cards have a phrase which is related to the word in the other set. The cards are jumbled. The students then have to match the right pairs.

Now I know part of the job ha been simplified thanks to the `ScatterView` on the Surface SDK. I have also decided that the best way is to create a `UserControl` which is then added to a `ScatterViewItem` at runtime. The words and the associated phrases are stored in a mySQL database or an access database.

But this is where I am having trouble. When the students do pair up a set of right cards how do I attach both the cards together? I looked at the Scatter puzzle included in the SDK but it seems a but too complex for this game at this stage. I wanted to create the cards resembling two torn pieces of paper which when attached form a bigger piece of paper but again I am not quite sure how to achieve this.